# Copy the data from one sheet to another

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet name sheet1, Cell no A2 contain Order No, Cell No A4 Contain Order Date, A4:A20 contain Type, B4:B20 contain Thickness, C4:C20 contain Size, D4:D20 contain Color, E4:E20 contain Quantity
Now i want to Copy the same data in Sheet2 as follows
Column A contain Order No, Column B Contain Order Date, Column C contain Type, Column D contain Thickness, Column E contain Size, Column F contain Color and Column G contain Quantity

```
function copyDataToSheet2() {
  var originalSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  var orderNoData = originalSheet.getRange('B1:B1').getValues();
  var orderDateData = originalSheet.getRange('D1:D1').getValues();
  var typeData = originalSheet.getRange('A3:A20').getValues();
  var thicknessData = originalSheet.getRange('B3:B20').getValues();
  var sizeData = originalSheet.getRange('C3:C20').getValues();
  var colorData = originalSheet.getRange('D3:D20').getValues();
  var quantityData = originalSheet.getRange('E3:E20').getValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < typeData.length; i++) {
    targetSheet.appendRow([
      orderNoData[i][0],
      orderDateData[i][0],
      typeData[i][0],
      thicknessData[i][0],
      sizeData[i][0],
      colorData[i][0],
      quantityData[i][0]
    ]);
  }
}
```

But its not working properly

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), like this:

```
function copyDataToSheet2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const orderNo = sourceSheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  const orderDate = sourceSheet.getRange('D1').getValue();
  const data = sourceSheet.getRange('A3:E').getValues();
  data.forEach(row => {
    if (row.join('')) {
      targetSheet.appendRow([orderNo, orderDate, ...row]);
    }
  });
}
```